# Fabric.js Guides/Bleed Lines

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js to build an editor that will output images for printing. These will be full bleed prints, and I need a way to show the bleed margin on top of everything else on the canvas.

The best solution that I have found so far is to just draw 4 lines on the canvas, but they are constantly getting put behind other objects and messing with the object stacking order.

It seems like there should be a simple solution for this. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I don't think I have any code that is relevant to the question. I am looking for an alternative method to what I already have.

Comment: Any update on this question, is it possible to make bleed and safety lines with Fabric that overlay the artwork underneath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your best bet is probably to make a group of those 4 lines and every time you add a new object to the page you need to also bring the group of lines to the front.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { 
 selection: true,
  preserveObjectStacking: true,
});
window.canvas = canvas;

var line1 = new fabric.Line([
  10, 0,
  10, canvas.height
],{ 
  stroke: '#000', 
})
var line2 = new fabric.Line([
  canvas.width - 10, 0,
  canvas.width - 10, canvas.height
],{ 
  stroke: '#000', 
})
var line3 = new fabric.Line([
  0, 10,
  canvas.width, 10
],{ 
  stroke: '#000', 
})
var line4 = new fabric.Line([
  0, canvas.height - 10,
  canvas.width, canvas.height - 10
],{ 
  stroke: '#000', 
});

var group = new fabric.Group([
 line1,
  line2,
  line3,
  line4
]);
group.selectable = false;
group.evented = false;

canvas.add(group);

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ 
  left: 300, 
  top: 300, 
  radius: 50, 
  fill: '#9f9', 
  originX: 'left', 
  originY: 'top',
  centeredRotation: true
}));
group.bringToFront();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your solution is very similar to the solution I already have, only I didn't know about the grouping feature. I was hoping for a completely different method for drawing guides on the canvas (one that doesn't use objects), but I will award you the answer if there isn't an alternative.

Comment: building guides as a fabric extension might be a cool little library to release. I don't know how to do it without have then in the object stack.

Comment: I was hoping for some kind of extension. I have already installed the "aligning guidelines" extension (https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/lib/aligning_guidelines.js) since it had some similar functionality, but there is no way to draw static guides. It shows dynamic guide lines that are not a part of the object stack.

Comment: nice! didn't even know that was there.

Comment: @StefanHayden by doing the group i am having problems because this group is getting the whole area of the canvas and is intended to be in front of all objects. Then i am having problems with the cursor and the moving of the inner objects. By the way, i am doing: var group = new fabric.Group([line1,...], {selectable: false, hasControls: false, hasRotatingPoint: false, hoverCursor: 'not-allowed'});

Comment: TBH the above is the smartest way to go: Just have specially marked objects as lines (and other helpful things), and you manage them accordingly. Aside from groups you could look at namespace collections too. The alternative would be to look at leveraging Fabric's background/foreground image feature or having an entirely separate <canvas> element (back and front) of the main <canvas>... in either case you're just inviting more management trouble and performance drawbacks. In the end you can't avoid the management aspect; no one knows what lines you want but you.